# ffmpeg rails error Could not parse output from FFProbe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, video, ffmpeg, screenshot

i tried to make a screenshot from my video
run this line

> movie = FFMPEG::Movie.new(Rails.root.join('lovetherents.mov').to_s)

but got error Could not parse output from FFProbe, also i got this error on another video with mp4 format. Also i get this error on any type of files and even if i pass a path just a directory like "/"
what's wrong?

Comment: If you output `Rails.root.join('lovetherents.mov').to_s`, does it return the correct path to the video?

Comment: absolutely, i tried to pass just a string path and get the same error

Comment: i also tried to inspect file and just copy path from here

Comment: Which version of ffmpeg are you using? From the streamio-ffmpeg github readme: "The current gem is tested against __ffmpeg 2.8.4__. So no guarantees with earlier (or much later) versions. _Output and input standards have inconveniently changed rather a lot between versions of ffmpeg_." The latest version of ffmpeg is 3.3.x, so if you're not running an old version of ffmpeg, the gem may be unable to parse the output information from ffmpeg.

Comment: Just use the CLI tool itself, no need for a dedicated library: `ffmpeg -ss 32.40 -i input.mp4 -frames:v 1 frame.png` for the frame at second 32.40.

Answer (score 0):

thanks everyone you save me for real
resolved by reinstalling to highest version, dunno why i have version like 2.+

> gem 'streamio-ffmpeg', '~> 3.0', '>= 3.0.2'

and reinstalling ffmpeg

> brew install ffmpeg --with-fdk-aac --with-libass --with-sdl2 --with-x265 --with-freetype --with-libvorbis --with-libvpx --with-opus

Answer (score 0):

Install library and try again:

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpegthumbnailer
```